# The use of the verb "speed" in context

Tags: word-usage

Let's say someone asks me why I like to snowboard and answer with ***because* *I like to speed***. What I am trying to say is that I like to move fast. Is it natural to use the verb *speed* in this context? Would it be more natural to use *speed* as a noun as in ***because I like speed***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Speed" as a verb is chiefly used in the context of driving a vehicle above the speed limit.

"I like going fast" or "I like the sense of speed" would be preferable to me over "because I like speed" even though it is grammatically correct - there are some contexts where it refers to amphetamine use.

Comment: We can use 'speed' as a verb meaning 'hurry', although it is a little archaic or poetic, and does not exactly fit the OP's meaning. I sped to my mother's house on learning that she was sick.

Comment: Requisite film reference: [I feel the need: the need for speed!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwNWviK5z0Q)

Comment: Requisite Dowland ayre reference: [What if I never speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a56Llxj2oH0)

Comment: The bridge [made it easier to get there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Skye_Boat_Song#Original_lyrics)